# rpm -rf not giving package name

Tags: rpm, rpm-spec

I am creating a symlink under %install section of RPM spec file.

`%install
(cd $RPM_BUILD_ROOT/boot && ln -s -f abc xyz)`

after installing the package, when I try to perform rpm -qf xyz
it says: /path/xyz is not owned by any package.

I want to make sure that perform rpm -qf xyz gives me name of correct package.
What changes do I need to make, in order to make this work. I tried mentioning this file in the %file section of RPM

`%files
/path/xyz`

But it still says xyz is not owned by any package.

Comment: Does `rpm -ql <package>` list the symlink? Is the symlink valid? Is `/path/xyz` (as used in your explanatory text) actually `/boot/xyz` (as used in the %install snippet)?

Comment: Yes, rpm -ql <package> lists the symlink that is valid. And yes /path/xyz is in fact /boot/xyz.

Comment: Can you show the output from `rpm -ql <package>`, `rpm -qf /boot/xyz`, `ls -l /boot/xyz` and `stat -L /boot/xyz`?